# Storm UI Internal Server Error for local cluster

Tags: apache-storm, internal-server-error

```
Internal Server Error

org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at backtype.storm.thrift$nimbus_client_and_conn.invoke(thrift.clj:75)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$all_topologies_summary.invoke(core.clj:515)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$fn__8018.invoke(core.clj:851)
    at compojure.core$make_route$fn__6199.invoke(core.clj:93)
    at compojure.core$if_route$fn__6187.invoke(core.clj:39)
    at compojure.core$if_method$fn__6180.invoke(core.clj:24)
    at compojure.core$routing$fn__6205.invoke(core.clj:106)
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2443)
    at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:106)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at compojure.core$routes$fn__6209.invoke(core.clj:111)
    at ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__6234.invoke(reload.clj:14)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$catch_errors$fn__8059.invoke(core.clj:909)
    at ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__6876.invoke(keyword_params.clj:27)
    at ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__6915.invoke(nested_params.clj:65)
    at ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__6848.invoke(params.clj:55)
    at ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__6943.invoke(multipart_params.clj:103)
    at ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__7124.invoke(flash.clj:14)
```

I follow the method in https://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/configuring-single-node-storm-cluster/ to set up my storm in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
When I try to connect to the Storm UI, the error as shown above.
My storm.yaml in /home/user/storm/conf is as below:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "localhost"

 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

 nimbus.host: "localhost"
 nimbus.thrift.port: 6627
# ui.port:8772

 storm.local.dir: "/home/user/storm/data"

 java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

 supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703
     - 6704
```

Anyone know how to solve this? I'm a newbie, a detail solution will be helpful.

My zoo.cfg is as below:

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000 

# The number of ticks that the initial synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10  

# The number of ticks that can pass between sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5  

# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/home/user/zookeeper-data  

# The location of the log file
 dataLogDir=/home/user/zookeeper/log/data_log 

# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181  
server.1=10.0.0.2:2888:3888  
server.2=10.0.0.3:2888:3888  
server.3=10.0.0.4:2888:3888  

# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3

# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

I run this in VMWare, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. What IP address should I put in the server.1 ?

Comment: can you make sure storm is up and running ? also did you start the storm ui manually ?

Comment: I used ./storm nimbus, ./storm supervisor & ./storm ui at my storm/bin directory.

Comment: How to check whether the storm is up & running?

Comment: check if [zookeeper is running](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_ConnectingToZooKeeper)   .. did you see anything in the logs ?

Comment: when I use ./zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181 at zookeeper/bin directory after I use ./zkServer.sh start at the same directory, the error below appear: 
2015-04-19 22:43:25,693 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-04-19 22:43:25,694 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1102] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)

Comment: how many zookeeper node you are running with ?  edit your question to put more details (don't put them in the comment please) , share the zoo.cfg file. You need to get zookeeper up and running before starting storm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your zookeeper is not running properly, before running zookeeper you have to create myid file that only contains id of each node.

please refer to here : [Zookeeper - three nodes and nothing but errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498507/zookeeper-three-nodes-and-nothing-but-errors)

Comment: I run the storm in VMWare Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I had only 1 zookeeper node, so what IP should I assign to the server.1 in zoo.cfg file in zookeeper/conf?

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved now. As you mentioned, I lack myid in my zookeeper/conf directory. And also there is an error in my zoo.cfg, if I'm using standalone mode, the server.1, server.2, server.3, autopurge, initLimit & syncLimit is not needed.