# Storm UI Internal Server Error on mac

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

```
org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:1156)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:1144)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$supervisor_summary.invoke(core.clj:414)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$fn__12602.invoke(core.clj:946)
```

I have checked many answers like [Storm UI Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694764/storm-ui-internal-server-error-for-local-cluster) about the issue but still can't solve it. My steps:

```
bin/zkServer.sh start
```

And I run this command:`bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181` to check whether the zookeeper is running properly and there are no errors. Then

```
bin/storm nimbus
bin/storm supervisor
bin/storm ui
```

So far anything looks good! But when I try to connect to the Storm UI through browser,the error as shown above and the browser stuck with "Loading summary" My storm.yaml in /home/user/storm/conf is as below:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "localhost"
nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]
```

My zoo.cfg is as below:

```
dataDir=/home/zookeeper-3.4.9/data
clientPort=2181
```

I run this on mac, the version of storm is 1.0.2, the version of zookeeper is 3.4.9.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Add:

If I change the version of storm to 0.8.1,Everything works well! my storm.yaml of storm-0.8.1 is as below:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
      - "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "/home/storm-0.8.1/storm"
supervisor.slots.ports:
      - 6700
      - 6701
      - 6702
      - 6703
storm.health.check.dir: "healthchecks"
storm.health.check.timeout.ms: 5000
nimbus.host: "localhost"
```